# AutoHotkey: How do i setup an array to string association from an using counters?

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

I have a simple array:

BuffArray := ["F5", "F7", "F8", "F9"]

I want to setup String variables from the array and be able to reference them by the array position.

Like:
BuffKey1 will be F5
BuffKey2 will be F7
BuffKey3 will be F8
BuffKey4 will be F9

I am trying to do it but I am not sure if this is the best approach:

```
BuffArray := ["F5", "F7", "F8", "F9"]
BuffTotal := BuffArray.Length()
KeyCount := 1

For i In BuffArray {
    BuffKey%KeyCount% := BuffArray[A_Index]
    BuffKeyVal := BuffKey%KeyCount%
    SendInput, BuffKey%i%
    MsgBox BuffTotal=(%BuffTotal%) BuffKey%KeyCount%=(%BuffKeyVal%)
    KeyCount++
}
```

Is there a smarter or more intuitive way to setup the string definitions that what I am doing??    I wasn't sure if i should use a LOOP sequence with i as a variable string for the counter..  etc.

Would appreciate any input

Comment: Have you considered to use an [associative Array](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Associative_Arrays)?

Comment: I don't really get the question, what are specifically looking to do? Seems to me you're creating some weird pseudo arrays and variables, and I can't really see what's the point of them.